# Exposing private IP addresses via a proxy

Tags: servlets, proxy, ip, server, network-protocols

I have faced an ambiguous scenario with private & public IP addresses. Please help me to understand it.

I'm integrating a payment gateway, which should be registered with the IP address/addresses that we are using to access that payment gateway.
We cannot make requests to the payment gateway using any IPs that are not registered with them.

My local machine has IP **x** but, when I google "what is my IP", I get IP address **y**, which is the public IP address of the network.

My machine is connected to a proxy server, through which we access the Internet.

I configured the IP address **y** with the payment gateway saying that I'll be making payment requests IP address **y**.

But I couldn't make payment requests and it gives me an error saying that the IP is not recognized.

But when I register my local IP **x** with the payment gateway, saying that I'll be making payment requests from IP **x**, it works.

What is the logic behind this? 
Is it the http headers that does the trick?

Comment: Is the payment gateway server-side or do you redirect the client there via HTTP?

Comment: I redirect the client to the payment page by submitting a form with relevant data such as merchant ID, Access code, Amount .etc

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is if there is a server-side component to this too. The server-side component may be picking up the effective server IP (**x**) and passing it server side to the payment gateway. My reasoning is that if it is 100% client-side then you would not have to set allowed IPs (as you would not necessarily know all your customer's IPs).

Comment: This is not related to the customer IPs. 
Only the Merchant IP should have be registered. User comes to my app, and he will be redirected to the payment gateway's payment page from my app. Redirect request is issued by my server.

Comment: Exactly what I was saying - find out what the Merchant IP is used for.